# Angular Style Attribute overlaps or dont hide

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I got a component that is visible when a condition is given or not given, its a  that is yellow. the code works fine. now I just want to change the color in some chases for example in blue.

`s-help-component.html`:

```
<div *ngIf="visible" class="s-help">
        <div class="s-help-content "><span [translate]="text"></span></div>
</div>
```

The class `s-help` is given in my global SCSS file. I wrote another CSS class in my global SCSS file and attached following in the code lines where I want to use my `s-help` component:

```
<s-help [visible]="true" class="s-help-v2" [text]="'SITEPLAN.INFO.101' | translate"></s-help>
```

The class `s-help-v2` defines that the border color is blue instead yellow.
My problem: it overlaps.

My try to solve the problem:
remove the class tag in the `s-help.component.html`, but when I do this, the border of the div is always visible even if the condition is false!

My SCSS:

```
.s-help-v2{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left calc(0.37em + 0.37rem);
    background-size: calc(1em + 1rem) calc(1em + 1rem);
    border: 2px solid $info !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block !important;   
    color: $gray-700;
    min-width: 220px;
    white-space: normal !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
}
```

Any suggestions how I can solve the overlapping problem, or the problem where the border color is active permanently.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion you can move the class `s-help` down to the child component level and this will fix the issue!

parent

```
<s-help [visible]="true" [text]="'SITEPLAN.INFO.101' | translate"></s-help>
```

child

```
<div *ngIf="visible" class="" [ngClass]="visible ? 's-help' : 's-help-v2'">
        <div [ngClass]="visible ? 's-help s-help-content' : 's-help-v2 s-help-content'"><span [translate]="text"></span></div>
</div>
```

Second way will be to make the `s-help-v2` style the child div like below!

```
.s-help-v2 > div {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to decide if ether that or this condition, in some chases i need the class s-help in other components i need s-help-v2

Comment: @du7ri add a @input binding `[customClass]="<required class>"` maybe that might help!